# This is my program when i return num_list it doesn't work but when i put print it work smoothly,

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, pyhamcrest

This is my program when i return num_list it doesn't work but when i put print it work smoothly,my program and another friend program is exactly same but his program working and mine not.

```
import random

def make_random_real():
    num_list = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        num_list.append(random.random())
    return num_list


make_random_real()
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"? What do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing? Please provide a [mcve] with full details.

Comment: Your code produces a list of floats. The result just goes nowhere. Why don't you assign it to some variable like `r = make_random_real()`

Answer (score 1):

In this version of the function, it just returns a value, so if you want to print it first you need to assign it to a variable like this:

```
result = make_random_real()
```

then you can `print(result)` which will show you the num_list in your function.

If you just want to print it without any assignment then just change `return num_list` to `print num_list` in your `make_random_real()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return value of the function to a value, so that you can print.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine ,

only you are not able to view output because you are not printing the returned result from the function.

```
import random

def make_random_real():
    num_list = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        num_list.append(random.random())
    return num_list


print(make_random_real())
```